# What is best(or proper) normalization method for A3C?

Tags: deep-learning, normalization, reinforcement-learning, batch-normalization

A3C[1] is an asynchronous online learning algorithm in deep reinforcement learning and it uses multiple workers to collect the independent samples asynchronously.

In my best knowledge, the popular normalization layer methods in computer vision(like batch normalization, layer normalization) are seldom applied in deep reinforcement learning.

In the A3C algorithm, what is the proper way to do normalization to help training? Can we use batch normalization in vision-based inputs under the settings of n-step bootstrapping?

[1]Asynchronous Methods for Deep Reinforcement Learning, https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01783

Comment: Layer normalization is used in DRL. Take a look at this paper please https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.01905